# Convert String value from a file to integer

Tags: java, bufferedreader, parseint

I am reading, from a file, integer values that I should use to calculate the function `multiple`.

However, after converting to integer, it appears that the integer variable doesn't hold them for further calculation.

Any help please?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Functions {

    int values, mul7, mul11, mul13;

    public static void main (String []args) { 

        Functions go = new Functions ();
        go.multiple();
        // will call functions here
    }

    public void multiple () {


        int a = 7;
        int b = 11;
        int c = 13;

        try {
            File inputFile = new File ("JavaInputData.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader (inputFile);

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (fileReader);

            String line = null;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) !=null)
                    {   
                        values = Integer.parseInt(line);
                        System.out.println(values);
                    }

            mul7 = values % a;
            mul11 = values %b;
            mul13 = values %c;

            System.out.println(mul7);

            reader.close();
            }

        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: You read the entire file in your `while` loop, so only the last value of `values` is actually used. Where's `values` defined anyway?

Comment: @PM77-1 It's a field. Defined at the top of the declaration of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Perform the calculation and output in the loop body. Something like,

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
{   
    values = Integer.parseInt(line);
    System.out.println(values);
    mul7 = values % a;
    mul11 = values % b;
    mul13 = values % c;
    System.out.printf("mul7 = %d, mul11 = %d, mul13 = %d%n", mul7, mul11, mul13);
}
```

Also, I suggest you use a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to `close()` your `Reader`;

```
try (File inputFile = new File ("JavaInputData.txt");
    FileReader fileReader = new FileReader (inputFile);
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (fileReader)) {
```

That way you don't have to call `close()` explicitly. But, if you're going to call `close()` explicitly; please do so in a `finally` block.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to properly calculate what I wanted in the loop before I print out the result wanted. However, I am still having NumberFormatException at runtime eventhough I have used in my code. Its apparently due to the string concatenation but how do I fix it? Can you elaborate more on your try resources tip?

Comment: @FabienL. For the `try-with-resources` I gave you a link to the documentation, and an example. As for the `String` concatenation, your posted code **doesn't**.